# How to access MTM field with through setting to template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

`price = models.ManyToManyField("price.Price", verbose_name='Ціни', through='services_count', through_fields=('service','price'), blank=True)`

and through model

```
class services_count(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Кількість цієї послуги у сервісі', null=True)
    service = models.ForeignKey("medservices.Medservices", verbose_name='Послуга або акція', on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)
    price = models.ForeignKey("price.Price", verbose_name='Ціна яка', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

views.py

```
def service_page(request, post_slug):

    post_content = Medservices.price.through.objects.all()
    post = get_object_or_404(Medservices, slug=post_slug)
    
    post_dict = {'post_rows':post , 'post_alt':post_content,}
    
    return render(request, 'medservices/service.html', context=post_dict)
```

So i want to have oportunity to access service_count model through model with MTM field